# Installing storybook in existing typescript react project throws error in stories

Tags: typescript, storybook

I just installed storybook in typescript react project but it started to throw error when i run yarn storybook. this is the code it generated and this is error it throws on "as" keyword

```
-- Error message
Parsing error: Missing semicolon

  10 |     backgroundColor: { control: 'color' }
  11 |   }
> 12 | } as Meta;
     |  ^
  13 |
  14 | const Template: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;
  15 |eslint

-- code 

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' }
  }
} as Meta;

-- my eslint config
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "eslint:recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],

  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // Allows for the parsing of JSX
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "import/first": "warn",
    "quotes": ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".tsx", ".ts"] }],
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ]
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    },
    "react": {
      "version": "latest" // "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with the same issue and the solution for me was to create a `.babelrc.json` file at the root directory of the project with the following configuration. (You need to install those dependencies)

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-transform-scss"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're missing the `@babel/preset-typescript` preset in your babelrc file.

The following is an example of my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-transform-scss"
  ]
}
```

You can install the preset with:

- `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript` or -
- `yarn add -D @babel/preset-typescript`

I've got other presets in there for a react project, but I hope this helps!

Here are the official docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript#installation

Sending kindness